# Bot Transcript in Azure Bot Composer

Tags: azure, bots, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I want to retrieve bot transcript, for bots built using composer , for conversation made till that particular point for a user  and send it to an API for downstream processing.

Is there a way to retrieve the transcript

Comment: You can refer to [Store Bot entire conversation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5534), [Manage stored blob transcripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#manage-stored-blob-transcripts) and [Transcripts not stored from bot in Azure](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8829)

Comment: Did you check the links mentioned in the above comment? Did you get the solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the bot SDK transcript logger. You'll need to configure the transcript store. Example to use the `MemoryTranscriptStore` (which is not recommended for production).

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ITranscriptLogger, MemoryTranscriptStore>();
    services.AddSingleton<IMiddleware, TranscriptLoggerMiddleware>();
}
```

You can also configure Azure blob storage via `BlobsTranscriptStore` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

To read the transcript, on the `OnTurnAsync` , inject the `ITranscriptLogger transcriptLogger`, and then you can use it:

```
var transcriptStore = transcriptLogger as ITranscriptStore;
var transcript = await transcriptStore?.GetTranscriptActivitiesAsync(turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);
if (transcript?.Items != null)
{
    foreach (var iactivity in transcript.Items)
    {
        var activity = iactivity as Activity;
        if (activity != null && activity.Type == "message")
        {
            var message2 = MakeMessage(
                conversationId,
                $"{activity.From.Name}: {activity.Text}");
        }
    }
}
```